# More efficient way to unnest arrays

Tags: sql, presto

I currently have a map<string, string>, where the value string is a concatenated, comma-separated, list. In a presto server, I have done the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    key, 
    unnested_tags
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.k,
        SPLIT(a.v, ',') AS v
    FROM table
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(tags) AS a (k, v)
)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(v) AS a (unnested_tags)
```

Is there a better way to unnest this map, while also unnesting the false array?

Comment: There isn't a single-step "unnest map while splitting values", however since Presto 316 the unnesting is more performant (https://prestosql.io/blog/2019/08/23/unnest-operator-performance-enhancements.html). However, I noticed your query uses `SELECT DISTINCT`. This may reduce query performance considerably -- is it needed?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I guess that was the better stating of my question, "is there a single-step for unnesting a nested array?"

In this case the distinct is necessary just because I was attempting to see what values the tags were and each row is an ID with a variety of options, so there would have been ~1M rows